# Get entities from my DB that are close to my current location

Tags: android, android-location

I have an access to DB which has the address of entities in terms of street number and name, city, country and postal code. Assuming all entities are Canada/US locations, is there a way (using google maps/location api or any other mechanism not involving an api) to search for these entities beside my current location? I just can't seem to find the way to approach this thing.

I know how to obtain my current position using GPS/network (in terms of long/lat). I am not sure how to proceed further?
Thank you

Comment: One option which I have used in the past is to store the long and lat of each address in the database then use an algorithm to determine the distance from your current position to the addresses stored.

Comment: I can't do that since the db is already designed and handed to me for read access only

Comment: I also forgot to mention the database was stored online and accessed using a web API. I think doing this or using the Google API is your best option. You need the long and lat to calculate the distance.